# How to refer particular class with conflicting names?

Tags: java, oop

I am not able to create a `java.awt.Rectangle` object in following code. However, I can still create Rectangle object...
Please explain why is it so?

```
package examples;
import java.awt.*;
public class Rectangle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
        System.out.println(rect.toString());    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Please explain why is it so?

You're creating an instance of *your* `Rectangle` class, but trying to assign it to a `java.awt.Rectangle` variable. You can just change it to:

```
java.awt.Rectangle rect = new java.awt.Rectangle();
```

Of course, you should try to avoid such naming collisions in the first place where possible, but you can always use the fully-qualified name, so long as the class is in a package. (Things get trickier in the default package, which you should avoid.)

Comment: The explanation - this is what makes it the best answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Rectangle` hides the class `Rectangle` from the package `java.awt`. You need the fully qualified name:

```
java.awt.Rectangle rect = new java.awt.Rectangle();
```

Answer (score 0):

do like

```
package examples;
import java.awt.*;

public class Rectangle {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.Rectangle rect = new java.awt.Rectangle();
    System.out.println(rect.toString());    
}
}
```